# Finding the middle row of different sized groupby within a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, finance, median

I have several daily yields and I have grouped them into months using the following code:

```
df2['trd_exctn_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['trd_exctn_dt'])

group_ym = df2.groupby(df2['trd_exctn_dt'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'))
```

I now want to find the middle row within each of these groups, however how would I do this as each group has a different number of rows in, therefore I cannot use a specific number to find the middle row

For example:

| cusip_id | yld_pt | trd_exctn_dt | trd_exctn_tm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00077TB0 | 6.58902 | 2015-01-05 | 578906.09 |
| 00077TB0 | 6.43672 | 2015-01-06 | 523452.12 |
| 00077TB0 | 6.45628 | 2015-01-07 | 555532.10 |
| 00077TB0 | 6.23452 | 2015-02-10 | 567392.02 |
| 00077TB0 | 6.34552 | 2015-03-12 | 545930.98 |

My desired answer would be:

| cusip_id | yld_pt | trd_exctn_dt | trd_exctn_tm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00077TB0 | 6.43672 | 2015-01-06 | 523452.12 |
| 00077TB0 | 6.23452 | 2015-02-10 | 567392.02 |
| 00077TB0 | 6.34552 | 2015-03-12 | 545930.98 |

Answer (score 1):

You can try `groupby` and a lambda function:

```
(df2.groupby(df2['trd_exctn_dt'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'))
    .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[(len(x)+1)//2])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use nth() function of group by for this.
   First get the order for the middle elements of each group.
2. Then, you can put your mid_id_list for each group into nth method as a parameter.

Sample Code:

```
mid_id_list = data.groupby(by=['Age'])['id'].count().apply(lambda x: x//2).tolist() 
data.groupby(by=['Age'])['id'].nth(mid_id_list)
```

Comment: Why `apply(lambda x: x//2)`? but not simply `//2`?

Comment: Hi your suggestion also works however in that case we need to put all the expression into bracket again to convert it into a list. Your suggestion is good and simpler but this is a more pandorable way.

Comment: @CanerBurcBASKAYA for some reason my output is not removing the rows that I want, and instead they still remain

Comment: @lds1 what is your output when you applied the concept?

Comment: Exactly the same as before the code has been applied

Comment: @lds1 could you please share the code line you run based on the sample code?

Comment: df2['trd_exctn_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['trd_exctn_dt']) -------->

mid_id_list = df2.groupby(by=['cusip_id',df2['trd_exctn_dt']])['cusip_id'].count().apply(lambda x: x//2).tolist() ------------->
df2.groupby(by=['trd_exctn_dt'])['cusip_id'].nth(mid_id_list)

Comment: @lds1 Could you please try this?  ----------> df2['trd_exctn_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['trd_exctn_dt'])  ---------->
mid_id_list = df2.groupby(df2['trd_exctn_dt'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'))['cusip_id'].count().apply(lambda x: x//2).tolist()  ---------->
df2.groupby(df2['trd_exctn_dt'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')).nth(mid_id_list)

Comment: @CanerBurcBASKAYA the same issue is still happening, the code that has been applied and the answer still remains the same

Comment: @lds1 sorry I'm out of ideas. There were supposed to be either a change -even it is not the desired one- or an error. The code works exactly as you want in another data frame.

Comment: I think it will work for the sample data I have used in the question, however I am trying to apply it to a large dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Previous replies didn't solve my issues:

- Apply is extremely slow for big dataframes
- `nth()` cannot be applied vectorized

It is possible to apply a vectorized method by:

- Create a sequential index (in my case the original index is not sequential)
- Groupby indexing columns and extract first position and #rows in block
- Calculate middle points with start & #rows
- Use to index to index

For my application this is 100x faster than the apply method:

```py
df['index'] = pd.RangeIndex(stop=df.shape[0])
# Extract group positions and number of rows
idxpos = df.groupby(idx_columns, sort=False, as_index=False, group_keys=False, dropna=False)['index'].agg(['first','count']).values
# Create middle rows position vector
idxmid = idxpos[:,0] + idxpos[:,1]//2
# Extract them and drop the index that we created
df_mids = df.iloc[idxmid].drop('index',axis=1)
```

Note that in case of an even number of rows it will return the upper one

If you already have a rangeindex as index, you can use `df.reset_index().groupby...` instead of declaring a new column. And of course, don't do the `.drop` at the end